# Reboot over ssh

Tags: ssh, reboot, router

I'm trying to reboot a Teltonika RTU950 using ssh.

I can log in as root via ssh and then reboot the router fine. However if i try to send the reboot command over ssh it does not work.

```
ssh root@routerip 'reboot'
```

This returns the error:

```
ash: reboot: not found
```

I've tried using shutdown -r instead. Also tried using absolute path. Always gives me the same error.

To be noted that the error says: `ash:` and not `bash:`.

The router runs on a linux os. uname gives:

```
Linux Teltonika-RUT950.com 3.18.44 #1
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your shell when you log in as root?
If it is indeed bash, then you can probably try:
`ssh root@routerip /bin/bash -c "/sbin/reboot"`

*Note that from a security perspective, enabling root login over SSH is a bad idea. You should check the vendor documentation to see if you can fix that.*

Comment: THANK YOU. You inherently helped me to get this to work. The shell is actually ash, not bash, even when i ssh interactively. So the command i should use, and works is: `ssh root@routerip "/bin/ash -c /sbin/reboot"`

Answer (score 4):

Try entering the full path to the reboot or shutdown command.  For example, if the full path to reboot is /sbin/reboot, run

ssh root@routerip /sbin/reboot

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that already. Same result unfortunately.

Comment: @LecauseAndThePi While logged into the host interactively, use `command -v reboot` to get the path for the `reboot` command, then use that in your `ssh` call.

Comment: i got the full path using `which` . Tried again with `command -v` to make sure and it's the same 'sbin/reboot/'

Comment: @LecauseAndThePi It is unlikely that the path is `sbin/reboot` and more likely that it's `/sbin/reboot` with a `/` at the start.

Comment: Yeah that's correct. Just bad typing on my part

Answer (score 0):

ssh -t root@device reboot

man ssh for the -t flag

The cause is without the -t flag you get a non-login shell and a different PATH. Besides that, even though giving the full path, the reboot command probably detects it's run non-interactively.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Still doesn't work. To be noted, the error says 'ash: reboot: command not found' . it is not 'bash'